# How to get posts from my Facebook profile page using Facebook PHP SDK v4?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I've made a simple php script to get posts from my Facebook profile page and it's working fine but I'm using Facebook PHP SDK v3 and Facebook API V1.0 (the Facebook App was created before April 30th 2014). Here is the script:

```
require 'facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => $appId,
    'secret' => $appSecret,
));

$posts = $facebook->api('/'.$fbUserId.'?fields=feed');

echo json_encode($posts);
```

Now I've created a new Facebook App and it requires to make calls to Facebook API v2.1. How to convert my script to work with Facebook PHP SDK v4 and API v2.1?

I have my new App ID, App secret and my App-scoped User ID (got it through Graph API Explorer Tool at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explore). I've also created an Access Token using the Graph API Explorer Tool with read_stream permissions. I've used this access token to create a Facebook session:

```
$session = new FacebookSession($accessToken);
```

Now the problem is that this access token only works while I'm logged. Once I'm logged out from Facebook the script stops displaying the posts from my profile. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: i believe the url is /userid/feed

Comment: You can use both methods. I'm getting the feed, but only while I'm logged in.